# DevExpress RibbonPageGroup not Scrolling correctly

Tags: wpf, scroll, devexpress, ribbon

I am using a `RibbonPageGroup` set to `AllowCollapse="False"` with an amount of `BarItemLink` items inside it.

For Example:

```
 <dxr:RibbonPage Caption="TestPage">
                    <dxr:RibbonPageGroup Name="pTestGroup" AllowCollapse="False">
                        <dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="bTestItem1" RibbonStyle="Large" />
                        <dxb:BarItemLink BarItemName="bTestItem2" RibbonStyle="Large" />
                    </dxr:RibbonPageGroup>
                </dxr:RibbonPage>
```

I am using `AllowCollapse` because i want the items to scroll horizontally. The problem i'am facing is that when i click the right scroll button it moves to the end of the items and when i click the left one it moves to the start. In other words the scrolling functionality is not working correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a DevExpress bug. Reproduced here: [Items in RibbonPageGroup are scrolled to the end each time scroll buttons are pressed](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T239571)